# Cannot remove java annotation processor from maven project

Tags: java, maven, annotation-processing

I'm about to refactor my dirty annotation processor. Therefore I wanted to create a new one to extract some responsibilities from the old one.

**old**: com.company.coma.shared.annotation.ComaToolAnnotationProcessor
**new**: com.company.coma.shared.annotation.ToolProcessor

Now I have removed the old one from the Configuration in my pom.xml

**pom.xml**

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <generatedSourcesDirectory>
                ${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/
            </generatedSourcesDirectory>
            <annotationProcessors>
                <annotationProcessor>
                    com.company.coma.shared.annotation.ToolProcessor
                </annotationProcessor>
                <!--<annotationProcessor>-->
                    <!--com.company.coma.shared.annotation.ComaToolAnnotationProcessor-->
                <!--</annotationProcessor>-->
            </annotationProcessors>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

I also **removed** the *ComaToolAnnotationProcessor.java* file completely and rebuild the whole project afterwards.

Still this is what my `clean install`

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project module-foo: Compilation failure
[ERROR] Annotation processor 'com.company.coma.shared.annotation.ComaToolAnnotationProcessor' not found
```

What is going on here? How can it still look for this even when I removed any namings of it from the whole project?

**EDIT#1**: Deactivating the whole annotation processing plugin (maven-compiler) did not help either. I don't understand what is going on. It seems like I have not influence to the dependencies or configurations anymore.

Comment: you have a dependency that needs it

Comment: @Zoe yeah I know - I'm looking for that dependency but could not find anything even with project wide grep for the processors name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I renamed one of my parent modules lately. But the submodules which actually contained the files to be processed still referred to the old parent artifact. That way all of my configuration of the thought to be new parent did not affected anything. Pretty weird since the the old parent module disappeared completely from my project structure but it surely was still available in my maven repo for sure.

I relied to much on the module-name refactoring feature of my IDE.

Comment: You can always check out a fresh copy of your sources and create a new project to see if the problem persists.

Comment: as i said its an issue with old, unused artifacts

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have (manually or not) added the processor to your `META-INF/services` file. Therefore it will try to run it, and fail upon not finding the class specified. I believe removing the reference might fix the problem :)

Comment: Sadly I have not produced any META-INF folder since the compilation does not succeed

Comment: If you are using maven, I think you can have a META-INF folder in you src folder, that will be copied when compiled. Probably not the case, though.